# Anyone develop any tools for generating documentation for elements?

Tags: polymer

Kinda like javadocs but for polymer-elements.

I get the feeling these were generated from a tool
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/polymer-elements.html
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/polymer-ui-elements.html

If no tools you can share specifically, maybe someone can share description of approach.  XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a proposal for self documenting elements.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15erfuJ9kGTTFZIxM1E8mKSdvZmb9RPr2BwMQvU48PVI

some examples were given

```
<wc-documentation name="my-tag">
  <summary>My tag is the bees knees.</summary>
</wc-documentation>
<wc-documentation name="my-tag" version="0.0.1"
                  github="https://github.com/Polymer/polymer"
                  home="http://polymer-project.org">
  <summary>...</summary>
  <pre class="example">...</pre>
</wc-documentation>
<wc-documentation name="my-tag">
  <div class="api">
    <p>This element supports the following methods:</p>
    <dl public>
      <dt>foo()</dt>
      <dd>Awesome method.</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl private>
      <dt>bar_()</dt>
      <dd>Privacy is key.</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</wc-documentation>
```

Discussion here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/polymer-dev/documentation/polymer-dev/NFQ4hIgZSo4/bBVvMD6_jMEJ

There was some concern to the amount of unessesary boiler plate within the elements. This finally led to a prototype for a document viewer element

http://polymer.github.io/polymer-doc-viewer/?//polymer.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/google-map.html&//polymer.github.io/polymer-localstorage/components/polymer-localstorage/polymer-localstorage.html

Comment: This represents two approaches I hadn't considered and gives me ideas for my own needs until a standard approach is adopted. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 3):

We are in the process of cleaning these things up and documenting the documentation tools just in the next couple of weeks. I'm sorry that it's all a bit rough around the edges today. Having said that, here is some info:

Polymer vends a [`polymer-doc-viewer`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-doc-viewer) component that you can point to (one or more) HTML files to generate documentation from source comments. Look at the `demo.html` to see some possible usage.

We also have [`polymer-docs`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-docs) component which will render docs for all polymer elements that it knows about that you have installed. Here is a live version installed at [`gh-pages`](http://polymer.github.io/polymer-docs/):

http://polymer.github.io/polymer-docs/components/polymer-docs/

The comment format is JSDoc-like, mostly copied from YUIDoc. The rendered output will probably get a face-lift soon, but this is one of the good parts: if we change it and then you update your copy of component, it will just work.

You can also customize or make your own `polymer-doc-viewer`, as the code is pretty simple. There is another component (included) called `context-free-parser` that actually snarfs up the documentation data into a JavaScript object (data model) so you can render it anyway you like.